# Django Nginx Reverse Proxy CSRF Cookie Not Set

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

**The Setup**

Using docker compose, I have the following:

`Nginx Reverse Proxy <> Docker Django Application with React pages (:8000)`

In my Nginx Reverse Proxy, the configuration under `conf.d` is as follows:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
        proxy_pass http://frontend:8000;
    }

}
```

In my Django Application, I have a view that sets a CSRF token as follows in `views.py`:

```
@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie, name='dispatch')`

class GetCSRFToken(APIView): ...
```

And on my Django app's react pages, I use Axios to call:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/csrf_cookie').then(...)
```

This gets my CSRF token and saves it as a cookie on the React page.

**The Problem**

Before deploying the nginx reverse proxy, while accessing the app via `localhost:8000`, CSRF token is set when I make the axios call to the above view and everything works.

However, after deploying the nginx reverse proxy, while accessing the app via `localhost`, the CSRF token is **not set** when I call the above view.

Another observation is that, with the nginx reverse proxy set up, if I visit `localhost:8000` directly, and call axios from there, the CSRF token **is set**.

It seems to be a issue with the reverse proxy. I can only get the cookie to be set to `localhost:8000` when I visit `localhost:8000` directly.

But when I visit `localhost:8000` via the reverse proxy from `localhost`, the CSRF token is **not set**.

Please advise how to solve this error. Much thanks!

My docker-compose setup:

```
version: "3"
   
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - nginx
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations frontendApp &&
             python manage.py makemigrations &&
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```